# MD simulations of liquid isopropanol predicts wrong thermodynamics proprieties

Tags: molecular-dynamics, thermodynamics

I am using GROMACS to run molecular dynamics simulations of pure liquids, in the NpT ensemble at room temperature and p = 1 atm. My first test was with isopropanol (also known as 2-propanol). I used about 500 molecules in a cubic box with size equal to 4 nm. I adopted the OPLS force-field, and my topology file was generated using LigParGen server. However, I am having problems with some results of my simulations. It thermalizes and describe well the liquid density and molar volume, however it predicts a Heat capacity $C_{p}$ greater than two times the experimental value. The isothermal compressibility is very wrong also. I don't know Where am I going wrong, does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you sure that the parameters you are using are correct? and 2. If you are using an already published set of parameters, are they parameterized to reproduce these values?

Comment: It's a well documented and known issue, which stems from the fact that you are using a classical harmonic oscillator for bonds. You can run a comparison with "constraints = all-bonds" to see the difference it makes. Here's a paper that might be useful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.13016.pdf